# How to iterate over string characters in ABAP in performant way?

Tags: abap

I would like to know if there are other(faster) ways to iterate over string in ABAP.

The naive approach - interating using substring access - is too slow on files of 100mb

```
DATA(lv_string) = |1234567890|.
DATA(lv_strlen) = strlen( lv_string ).
DO ( lv_strlen - 1 ) TIMES.
  DATA(lv_current_symbol) = lv_string+sy-index(1).
ENDDO.
```

I achieved 50% performance increase by assigning chunks of string to the field of type c with maximum length and then assigning field symbol to it - but it is only 50% increase and the code looks ugly

```
CLASS lcl_ IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD main.

    "prepare the file to parsed
    DATA(lv_file) = me->get_file(  ).

    DATA lv_chunk TYPE c LENGTH 262143.
    CONSTANTS lc_chunk_size TYPE int4 VALUE 262143.
    DATA(lv_strlen) = strlen( lv_file ).

    GET TIME STAMP FIELD DATA(lv_time_stamp).
    WRITE / lv_time_stamp.

    DATA(lv_times) = lv_strlen DIV lc_chunk_size.
    IF ( lv_strlen  MOD lc_chunk_size > 0 ).
      lv_times = lv_times + 1.
    ENDIF.


    DO lv_times TIMES.
      DATA(lv_offset) = lc_chunk_size * ( sy-index - 1 ).
      IF  sy-index   = lv_times.
        DATA(lv_length) = lv_strlen MOD lc_chunk_size.
      ELSE.
        lv_length = lc_chunk_size.
      ENDIF.
      lv_chunk = lv_file+lv_offset(lv_length).
      FIELD-SYMBOLS <char1> TYPE c.

      ASSIGN lv_chunk+0(1) TO <char1>.
      DATA(lv_actual_length) = lv_length - 1.
      DO lv_actual_length TIMES.
        ASSIGN lv_chunk+sy-index(1) TO <char1>.
      ENDDO.

    ENDDO.

    GET TIME STAMP FIELD lv_time_stamp.
    WRITE / lv_time_stamp.
    DATA(lv_naive_strlen) = ( lv_strlen - 1 ).
    DO lv_naive_strlen TIMES.
      DATA(lv_current_symbol) = lv_file+sy-index(1).
    ENDDO.
    GET TIME STAMP FIELD lv_time_stamp.
    WRITE / lv_time_stamp.
  ENDMETHOD.


  METHOD get_file.
    DATA lv_file_line TYPE string.
    DO 10 TIMES.
      lv_file_line = |1234567890,{ lv_file_line }|.
    ENDDO.
    lv_file_line = lv_file_line && |;|.

    DATA(lt_file_as_table) = VALUE string_table(
        FOR i = 1 THEN  i + 1 UNTIL  i = 1000000
            ( lv_file_line ) ).

    CONCATENATE LINES OF lt_file_as_table INTO r_result.


  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

Does anyone have a better approach?

Update - there was a question why I need this - basically I need to parse a CSV file according to the RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180

Update - I have updated the code and checked using my S4H developer edition. The chunked approach is taking 39 seconds for me and the naïve approach is taking 70 seconds. I guess this is less than 50% (but even with 50% improvement the code is quite ugly)

Update - just to show how much faster it could be you can run the following Java class. On my machine the performance difference is... staggering

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String lv_file = get_file();

        var lt_char_array = lv_file.toCharArray();
        var lv_char_array_length = lt_char_array.length;
        var lv_counter = 0;
        for (char lv_char : lt_char_array) {
            if (lv_char == ';'){
                lv_counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lv_counter);
    }

    private static String get_file() {
        StringBuilder lv_file_line = new StringBuilder("1234567890,");
        lv_file_line.append(String.valueOf(lv_file_line).repeat(10));
        lv_file_line.append(";");
        return String.valueOf(lv_file_line).repeat(1000000);
    }
}
```

Comment: And why would you need that? There are various things the ABAP kernel can do you for you (way faster).

Comment: Apart from that your approach is quite clever (I guess the performance achievement comes from less heap access), I'd experiment with different chunk sizes, not sure if the maximum char size is the optimum

Comment: It intrigued me. After a few tests, I can't find better but I don't get this 50% difference. I didn't push further but I feel it's the same performance for both (7.52 on Linux VM on my Windows laptop): 60 seconds for reading 100 MB character by character. If you need to parse 100 MB quickly, maybe ABAP is not the best option (except if it's the thing Jonas has mentioned).

Comment: I would be glad to know how ABAP kernel can help me resolve it. I don't think the customer would agree to allow me to write/deploy C libraries though

Comment: Do you need all values from the CSV or just specific ones? Also then maybe it is faster to read line by line, and then `SPLIT` by comma into the fields you need?

Comment: It is a generic inbound - the semantic layer is coming later.   

of course it is faster to split  - but to accommodate to the RFC, you first need to read character by character since you do not know whether the new line is contained within escape characters or not

Comment: I just looked at POSIX RegEx, the performance is not better, and also puts the system on its knees with such big CSV. PCRE RegEx (from ABAP 7.55) seems much more interesting but I don't have ABAP 7.55 to test it.

Comment: I checked Regex, but I also found out that it is not that really that performant, and the complexity of such a regex statement is too high. My target stack is 7.50, so PCRE is out of question.

Comment: For what it's worth I can reproduce the 50% speed increase, however the server I'm running on is twice as fast as your's ;) (chunk: 11 sec, naive: 22 sec)

Comment: I needed to upgrade my toaster long time ago. But coronavirus and bitcoin kinda put that on ice.
I tested the JS approach  - it is even slower that ABAP native. I updated the question

Comment: I don't think that comparing so many programming languages with so many different compilation pipelines involved will really get you any meaningful results. ABAP is optimized for table processing with fixed sized strings (cause that's what it's built for), whereas other languages are optimized towards other goals (e.g.  V8 being optimized towards fast page load time, aka. initial execution time)

Comment: Well, I would like to achieve Java like performance in ABAP if this is possible (I do not ask for C/Rust level of performance in this case). The JS is part of ABAP kernel (although obsolete one) so it was still a possibile solution(did not work out).

Answer (score 1):

> How to iterate over string characters in ABAP in performant way?

You don't. Iterating over strings character by character in higher level programming languages will always be slower than what the engine can do at a lower level. Thus you can always achieve better performance by utilizing capabilities of the engine (the ABAP kernel) such as the inbuilt parsers for XML and JSON, the regular expression engine (especially with [JIT compiling](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/12/10/modern-regular-expressions-in-abap-part-1-introducing-pcre/#just-in-time-compilation)), and if you really have something that cannot be covered by those, by using the inbuilt string methods (`SPLIT`, `substring`, `find` and the alike).

For parsing CSV one could do something like this (and you'll probably find similar approaches for whatever string processing you're trying to do):

```
  METHOD parse_chunk_line.
    SPLIT i_file AT cl_abap_char_utilities=>newline INTO TABLE DATA(lines).

    LOOP AT lines ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>).
      SPLIT <line> AT ',' INTO TABLE DATA(values).

      LOOP AT values ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<value>).
        DATA(value_len) = strlen( <value> ) - 1.

        IF <value>+0(1) = '"'.
          " Value opened
        ENDIF.

        IF <value>+value_len(1) = '"'.
          " Value closed
        ENDIF.
      ENDLOOP.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD.
```

In my test environment this outperforms your "chunk approach" by a factor of 3 (running in 5s which is I think quite okay for processing 100MB),
though I think these tests are not giving you any meaningful results. Implement all three approaches in a real world scenario, then run it on a "real" ABAP system if you want measures one can draw conclusions from.

You noted that

> but to accommodate to the RFC, you first need to read character by character since you do not know whether the new line is contained within escape characters or not

This is true, so I would simply keep a boolean whether you're in a literal (an opening " was found but no closing one), then "reconstruct" the actual value by readding the newlines and commas in the loop. That way in the case where there are no newlines or commas in a value (I hope this is a corner case), the code takes the "fast path" and you can simply store `<value>` into your resulting datastructure.

---

For what it's worth, here's my microbenchmark:

```
CLASS Z_CSV DEFINITION
  PUBLIC
  FINAL
  CREATE PUBLIC .

PUBLIC SECTION.
  CLASS-METHODS run.
  CLASS-METHODS get_file
   RETURNING VALUE(r_result) TYPE string.

  CLASS-METHODS parse_chunk
    IMPORTING i_file TYPE string.
  CLASS-METHODS parse_naive
    IMPORTING i_file TYPE string.
  CLASS-METHODS parse_chunk_line
    IMPORTING i_file TYPE string.

PROTECTED SECTION.
PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.



CLASS Z_CSV IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD get_file.
    DATA lv_file_line TYPE string.
    DO 10 TIMES.
      lv_file_line = |1234567890,{ lv_file_line }|.
    ENDDO.
    lv_file_line = lv_file_line && |;|.

    DATA(lt_file_as_table) = VALUE string_table(
        FOR i = 1 THEN  i + 1 UNTIL  i = 1000000
            ( lv_file_line ) ).

    CONCATENATE LINES OF lt_file_as_table INTO r_result.
  ENDMETHOD.



  METHOD parse_chunk.
    DATA(value_count) = 0.

    DATA lv_chunk TYPE c LENGTH 262143.
    CONSTANTS lc_chunk_size TYPE int4 VALUE 262143.
    DATA(lv_strlen) = strlen( i_file ).


    DATA(lv_times) = lv_strlen DIV lc_chunk_size.
    IF ( lv_strlen  MOD lc_chunk_size > 0 ).
      lv_times = lv_times + 1.
    ENDIF.


    DO lv_times TIMES.
      DATA(lv_offset) = lc_chunk_size * ( sy-index - 1 ).
      IF  sy-index   = lv_times.
        DATA(lv_length) = lv_strlen MOD lc_chunk_size.
      ELSE.
        lv_length = lc_chunk_size.
      ENDIF.
      lv_chunk = i_file+lv_offset(lv_length).
      FIELD-SYMBOLS <char1> TYPE c.

      ASSIGN lv_chunk+0(1) TO <char1>.
      DATA(lv_actual_length) = lv_length - 1.
      DO lv_actual_length TIMES.
        ASSIGN lv_chunk+sy-index(1) TO <char1>.

        IF <char1> = ','.
          value_count = value_count + 1.
        ENDIF.
      ENDDO.

    ENDDO.


    WRITE |Chunk counted { value_count }|.
  ENDMETHOD.


  METHOD parse_chunk_line.
    DATA(value_count) = 0.

    SPLIT i_file AT cl_abap_char_utilities=>newline INTO TABLE DATA(lines).

    LOOP AT lines ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>).
      SPLIT <line> AT ',' INTO TABLE DATA(values).

      LOOP AT values ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<value>).
        value_count = value_count + 1.

        DATA(value_len) = strlen( <value> ) - 1.

        IF <value>+0(1) = '"'.

        ENDIF.

        IF <value>+value_len(1) = '"'.

        ENDIF.
      ENDLOOP.
    ENDLOOP.

    WRITE |Line chunked counted { value_count }|.
  ENDMETHOD.



  METHOD parse_naive.
    DATA(value_count) = 0.
    DATA(lv_strlen) = strlen( i_file ).
    DATA(lv_naive_strlen) = ( lv_strlen - 1 ).
    DO lv_naive_strlen TIMES.
      DATA(lv_current_symbol) = i_file+sy-index(1).
      IF lv_current_symbol = ','.
        value_count = value_count + 1.
      ENDIF.
    ENDDO.

    WRITE |Naive counted { value_count }|.
  ENDMETHOD.


  METHOD run.
    DATA prepare_start TYPE timestampl.
    GET TIME STAMP FIELD prepare_start.

    DATA(file) = get_file(  ).

    DATA prepare_end TYPE timestampl.
    GET TIME STAMP FIELD prepare_end.

    WRITE |Preparation took { cl_abap_tstmp=>subtract( tstmp1 = prepare_end tstmp2 = prepare_start ) }|.


    DATA naive_start TYPE timestampl.
    GET TIME STAMP FIELD naive_start.
    parse_naive( file ).
    DATA naive_end TYPE timestampl.
    GET TIME STAMP FIELD naive_end.

    WRITE |Naive run took { cl_abap_tstmp=>subtract( tstmp1 = naive_end tstmp2 = naive_start ) }|.


    DATA chunk_start TYPE timestampl.
    GET TIME STAMP FIELD chunk_start.
    parse_chunk( file ).

    DATA chunk_end TYPE timestampl.
    GET TIME STAMP FIELD chunk_end.
    WRITE |Chunk run took { cl_abap_tstmp=>subtract( tstmp1 = chunk_end tstmp2 = chunk_start ) }|.

    DATA line_start TYPE timestampl.
    GET TIME STAMP FIELD line_start.
    parse_chunk_line( file ).

    DATA line_end TYPE timestampl.
    GET TIME STAMP FIELD line_end.
    WRITE |Line Chunk run took { cl_abap_tstmp=>subtract( tstmp1 = line_end tstmp2 = line_start ) }|.

  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

Comment: I think, this solution answers a different question  - how to parse a CSV file in ABAP in a performant way. Right now your iteration relies on the fact that there are new lines and commas in the file - whereas I am interested in a solution that would not have such a dependency.  If I will change the way I prepare the file (replace the new lines with pipelines and commas with semicolons ) your solution will degrade to naive approach
You also assume that csv files have moslty no escape characters, which is very often not the case (many applications put all fields in CSV enclosed in parenthesis)

Comment: @DmitryYudin there is no single scenario I could think of where you actually have to read every single character of a string. If your Data is context free, you can use the RND parser built into the ABAP kernel, if your data is regular, you can use the regex engine (PCRE probably outperforms POSIX by magnitudes), if your data is based on some common data format (XML, JSON, CSV?) you can use inbuilt functionality of the ABAP platform (which in many cases is implemented in C++ in the ABAP kernel)

Comment: ... and in case you "invent your own dataformat" then probably you have at least some structure in it, which allows you to utilize `SPLIT` or other string processing utilities.

Comment: Could you possibly share some more info on RDN parser built into ABAP kernel and how this can be reached from ABAP?

Comment: I will most likely open another question about CSV processing in abap and there we can continue this very interesting discussion(I will definitely try to split the file and check if this brings performance gains - I tried it already, but may be last time I did something wrong ). For now I am really interested in the question that I originally asked.

Comment: Btw, are you sure that the class CL_RND_GENERIC_PARSER can be consumed from z code? I think I once tried to consume the Abstract syntax tree parser of ABAP - but there was some error that sounded like customer should not be using that functionality

Comment: Yeah, could be ... then forget about it ;)

Comment: Ok, so I adjusted the benchmark you provided (you were not actually iterating over the strings) and your approach is little bit faster with iteration (most likely due to the fact that you removed) a lot of symbols with split but still slower than the chunked approach
Real life csv files have 1. All fields enclosed into parentheses 2. Escaped parenthesis inside of the field 3. new lines inside parenthesis 4. commas in parentheses. 5. Very big texts as a one field . This is why the approach you are proposing  is not going to work

Comment: Why would you iterate over the strings? What purpose would that have?

Comment: just answered - you are significantly simplifying the real world with the split string approach. I think the code that would handle all the border cases of csv files and use split string approach would be very complex

Comment: just to bring a puzzle - imagine the csv defined like this
"I"",""ha""te","csv","files"; 
just to confirm - there are only 3 fields here

Comment: @DmitryYudin Nice reinventing the wheel I must say. What about the function module `KCD_CSV_FILE_TO_INTERN_CONVERT`? Or os it also not available in your system?

Comment: @Jagger well, the question we're discussing here is "How to iterate over string characters in ABAP in performant way?". If it were "How to parse CSV in ABAP?" then the obvious answer would be to look for an existing implementation. The comment of you should really be towards the question, right?

Comment: @Jagger well, as a matter of fact it is not available in my system. On the other hand, I will check the implementation  of that function module - many SAP standard implementations are using split approach and are not implementing RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180 fully

Comment: @Jagger I checked the coding of the function module you mentioned. I will need to do some more research but 1. I do not think it will handle the new line in the escaped CSV field, 2. If the field length is exceeding C field limit, it will dump. It also uses the same iteration process so the performance will be approximately the same as chunked approach, with the side effect of not accepting all possible CSV formats

Comment: @DmitryYudin `Why would you iterate over the strings? What purpose would that have?` agree with Jonas. Every task should have a final goal, and such synthetic tests like iterating strings are not interesting nor meaningful. You were proposed several solutions for your CSV task which you rejected with no clear reason, and in such way you maybe heading to the wrong turn, where string iteration is a useless step in the solution to real task

Comment: @Suncatcher I think, if you find my question not interesting, you do not need make a comment about it. If you want to propose the solution to parse the CSV according to RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180 that would be faster than chunked approach , I am all ears (I am serious here - I would really love to have such a solution)

Comment: @dmitry then ask another question, specific to CSV and I'd be glad to answer ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840370/abap-how-to-parse-csv-file-in-the-most-performant-way

Answer (score -1):

Why on Earth would you do that when there is already a standard function module `CONVERT_STRING_TO_TABLE`, which does exactly what your beloved `String.toCharArray()` does?

```
REPORT zzz.

DATA: gt_char_array TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF char1 WITH EMPTY KEY.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERT_STRING_TO_TABLE'
    EXPORTING
      i_string               = `123456789`
      i_tabline_length       = 1
*     I_UNICODE              =
    TABLES
      et_table               = gt_char_array.
  BREAK-POINT.
```

There is also the following function module `KCD_CSV_FILE_TO_INTERN_CONVERT`. There are plenty of options for example [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/09/understanding-csv-files-and-their-handling-in-abap/) which allow you to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: If you check the coding inside the function module, you will find there the same old DO ( lv_strlen - 1 ) TIMES.
  DATA(lv_current_symbol) = lv_string+sy-index(1).
ENDDO.
So there is no performance gain here
Also, this is HR specific FM, I do not have in in the system I am working with