# Using CL_FDT_XL_SPREADSHEET class for a .CSV possible?

Tags: csv, xlsx, abap

I have a program that maintains custom Z tables by exporting the table to an excel spreadsheet and it also refreshes the table and updates from an excel spreadsheet with .XSLX files.

However, I also want the program to accept .CSV files.

I use the `CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES=>GUI_UPLOAD` method to get the raw data, but when I try to convert the raw data to an `XSTRING`, an error is thrown

My question: Is the `CL_FDT_XL_SPREADSHEET` class suitable for .CSV file data or is it only suitable for .XLSX files?

The upload to SAP from .XLSX is done with the `CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES=>GUI_UPLOAD` method to get the raw data. Then converted to `XSTRING` and passed into the `CL_FDT_XL_SPREADSHEET` class and the `IF_FDT_DOC_SPREADSHEET~GET_ITAB_FROM_WORKSHEET` method is called to pass that data to a variable where it is used in another method to upload to SAP. This works fine.

Code:

```
METHOD import_excel_data.

    DATA: lt_xtab TYPE cpt_x255,
          lv_size TYPE i.

    IF i_filetype = abap_true. "******.XLSX UPLOAD*********
      cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_upload( EXPORTING filename   = i_file
                                                      filetype   = 'BIN'
                                            IMPORTING filelength = lv_size
                                             CHANGING data_tab   = lt_xtab
                                             EXCEPTIONS
                                                      file_open_error = 1
                                                      file_read_error = 2
                                                      error_no_gui            = 3
                                                      not_supported_by_gui    = 4
                                                      OTHERS                  = 5 ).
      IF sy-subrc <> 0.
        RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE zcx_excel_exception EXPORTING i_message = |Invalid File { i_file }| ##no_text.
      ENDIF.
    ELSE."******.CSV UPLOAD*********

      cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_upload( EXPORTING filename   = i_file
                                                      filetype   = 'ASC'
                                                      has_field_separator = abap_true
                                            IMPORTING filelength = lv_size
                                            CHANGING data_tab   = lt_xtab
                                            EXCEPTIONS
                                                    file_open_error = 1
                                                    file_read_error = 2
                                                    error_no_gui            = 3
                                                    not_supported_by_gui    = 4
                                                    OTHERS                  = 5 ).
      IF sy-subrc <> 0.
        RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE zcx_excel_exception EXPORTING i_message = |Invalid File { i_file }| ##no_text.
      ENDIF.

    ENDIF.

    cl_scp_change_db=>xtab_to_xstr( EXPORTING im_xtab    = lt_xtab
                                              im_size    = lv_size
                                    IMPORTING ex_xstring = DATA(lv_xstring) ).

    DATA(lo_excel) = NEW cl_fdt_xl_spreadsheet( document_name = i_file
                                                xdocument     = lv_xstring ).
    lo_excel->if_fdt_doc_spreadsheet~get_worksheet_names(
      IMPORTING worksheet_names = DATA(lt_worksheets) ).

    rt_table = lo_excel->if_fdt_doc_spreadsheet~get_itab_from_worksheet( lt_worksheets[ 1 ] ).

    IF rt_table IS INITIAL.
      RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE zcx_excel_exception EXPORTING i_message = 'No Data found in Excel File' ##no_text.
    ENDIF.
  ENDMETHOD.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the CL_FDT_XL_SPREADSHEET class suitable for .CSV file data or is it only suitable for .XLSX files?

No. **CL_FDT_XL_SPREADSHEET** is based on ABAP [iXML framework](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenabap_ixml_lib.htm) and works purely with XML formats compliant with [OOXML specification](http://officeopenxml.com/) which XLSX is also based on.

CSV is nowhere near this pre-requisite, so it won't work.

Comment: Thanks @suncatcher, that makes sense

I've managed to get the CSV data into a table, loop at the table splitting at the comma putting it into another table

I then want to put it into a dynamic table which will be used to refresh the and update the Z custom table.

Do you think this is a good approach? I am in my first year working with ABAP so please excuse my inexperience

Comment: check methods of `cl_rsda_csv_converter` class, it was created to simplfy CSV handling, check also the solution from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840370/how-to-parse-csv-file-in-the-most-performant-way